# How to continue from the 'if' statement to the 'elif' in Python?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, python-3.x, count

How does one continue from the `if` statement to the `elif`?  I would like the end result to be 'mybadgr' but instead it keeps printing out 'badgr'.

```
a = "Badger"
vowels = 'AEIOUaeiou'
flicker = len(a)
if a[flicker - 2] in vowels and a[flicker -1] in'r':
    final = str(a[:flicker-2])+'r'
    flicker = len(str(final))
    #continue the if to elif
elif flicker < 6:
    final = 'My'+final
```

Comment: The `el` in `elif` means "else". It only gets evaluated at all if the previous if/elifs' conditions are false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a set of `if` - `elif` - `else` statements, Python will only ever execute *one* of the suites. The first `if` or `elif` condition to return `True` determines what block is picked; if none match then `else` is executed.

Instead of `elif`, use `if` to start a new block:

```
if a[flicker - 2] in vowels and a[flicker -1] in'r':
    final = str(a[:flicker-2])+'r'
    flicker = len(str(final))

if flicker < 6:
    final = 'My'+final
```

Now it is a separate `if` suite and will be tested separately from the preceding `if`.

Note that you don't need to use `flicker` to index from the end; negative indices achieve the same:

```
if a[-2] in vowels and a[-1] == 'r':
    a = a[:-2] + 'r'

if len(a) < 6:
    a = 'My{}'.format(a)
```

This achieves the same result (albeit just setting `a`) without the need for the `flicker` length variable.

Comment: what happen if the flicker is above 6 wouldnt you get a string error

Comment: @user2699284: why would you?

Comment: @user2699284: If your *first* `if` statement doesn't match, but the second does, then `final` has not been set, most likely.

Comment: sorry about the long reply i was redoing my codes to match yours

Comment: by the way the code on stack overflow which i posted was an example i made